Independence of $p$-adic valuation and absolute value $v_\infty$
There is a theorem in a book I am reading:

(Indepedence of Valuations) Let $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ be prime numbers and $a,a_1,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb Q$. For any $\varepsilon>0$ and positive integers $l_1,\cdots,l_n$, there is some $b\in\mathbb Q$ such that

$v_\infty(b-a)<\varepsilon$
$v_{p_i}(b-a_i)\leq p_i^{-l_i}$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$


Here $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation, and $v_\infty(x)=|x|$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$. The proof given was

Let $m$ be the least common denominator of $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ and let $p_i^{-s_i}=v_{p_i}(m)$, $r_i=l_i+s_i$, $r=\max\left\{1,r_1,\cdots,r_n\right\}$. Then by Chinese remainder theorem, there is some $c$ such that $c\equiv ma_i\mod p_i^r$ for all $i$, and hence
$$
v_{p_i}(c-ma_i)\leq p_i^{-r}\Longrightarrow v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)\leq p_i^{-l_i}
$$
This means $\frac cm$ satisfies the condition 2. we require. We modify it to $b$ so it satisfies condition 1. Let $q=(p_1\cdots p_n)^r$, then there are integers $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
|b-a|:=\left\vert\frac cm\frac{1+uq}{1+vq}-a\right\vert<\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $v_\infty(b-a)<\varepsilon$ is granted. By strong triangular inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
v_{p_i}(b-a_i)\leq\max\left\{v_{p_i}\left(b-\frac cm\right),v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)\right\}\leq v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)\leq p_i^{-l_i}
\end{align}
$$
Thus proved. $\blacksquare$

What I do not understand here is why $v_{p_i}\left(b-\frac cm\right)\leq v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)$. I know that
$$
v_{p_i}\left(b-\frac cm\right)=v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm\right)\cdot v_{p_i}\left(\frac{(u-v)(p_1\cdots p_n)^r}{1+v(p_1\cdots p_n)^r}\right)=v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm\right)p_i^{-r}\cdot v_{p_i}(u-v)
$$
But this does not imply this is smaller than $v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)$. For example, if $\frac cm-a_i=0$, then $v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)=0$, and then to make $v_{p_i}\left(b-\frac cm\right)\leq v_{p_i}\left(\frac cm-a_i\right)$ hold there must be $u=v$. This is impossible as $\varepsilon$ is chosen arbitrarily. Hence, I think this proof is wrong. How can I choose some $b$ to prove the theorem in correct way?

I think there is some confusion here between some $p$-adic valuation and $p$-adic norm. Already in your statement of "independence of valuations" there is a problem. If (as you say, and this is also consistent with standard notation)  $v_{p_i}$ is the $p_i$-adic valuation, then the condition $v_{p_i}(b-a_i)\leq p_i^{-l_i}$ seems wrong. Rather, I think the intended meaning is $|b-a_i|{p_i}\leq p_i^{-l_i}$, or equivalently $v{p_i}(b-a_i)\geq l_i$.

Care to engage ?

@EwanDelanoy Sorry... I did not look at this site these days... It seems the book I am reading (Moh's Algebra I in Chinese) calls $p$-adic norm $p$-adic valuation, and here $v_{p_i}$ stands for $p$-adic norm. (He defines $v_p(a)=p^{-l}$.)

It seems "valuation" refers to norm throughout the book. In p34 he defined his $p$-adic valuation, and in p113 he defined "valuation" formally. I looked up in Wikipedia and it was actually the definition of norm.

It is a typo. Corrected.

You're almost there. In your product (let us call it $P$) $P=\frac {v_{p_i}(c)}{v_{p_i}(m)}\cdot p_i^{-r}\cdot v_{p_i}(u-v)$, notice that as $c$ and $u-v$ are integers, we must have
$v_{p_i}(c)\leq 1$ and $v_{p_i}(u-v)\leq 1$. It follows that
$$
P \leq \frac {1}{v_{p_i}(m)} \cdot p_i^{-r} = p_i^{s_i} \cdot p_i^{-r} \leq p_i^{s_i} \cdot p_i^{-r_i} = p_i^{-l_i}. 
$$

Could the downvoter please explain his or her reasons ?
